# How to fix Ubuntu 13.10 locking up due to disk IO

Tags: nvidia, 13.10

I've been an Ubuntu fan for many years, and have had no issues to speak of so far, but since I've bought a new laptop, I've run into an issue that I can't figure out how to deal with.

After about 2-3 hours of sustained usage, my computer irrevocably locks up completely. It starts running slowly for a few minutes, having some stutter and other issues, and eventually the entire system just freezes.

I've been able to capture a screen of my `iotop` when the problem is occuring, which seems to be the issue. `top` is showing nothing out of the ordinary, except a steadily increasing load. Please note that this is the last I saw anything on my screen change, after this it was completely frozen.

[image: iotop]

I'm quite out of my depth. Since none of the programs I'm running seem to be the culprit specifically, I can't really uninstall something and be done.

The system in question is a laptop with the following specs:

> Intel Core i7 620M 2,66GHz
>   Quadro FX 880M
>   4GB DDR3
>   7200rpm 320GB

How could I fix (or find) this issue?

Comment: But can you try to correlate your problem to a particular application? I've found I need to watch LibreOffice Calc carefully.

Comment: I'll try to shut it down next time I see the symptoms. It does not appear to be using excessive CPU, Memory or IO. Though I'm not sure it would even be reading from disk in that situation, considering I wasn't doing anything with it.

Comment: Looks like you are out of ram and swapping like mad.

Comment: Hmm, anything I can do about that except use less programs or buy/install more RAM? How would I prevent for example chrome from eating up all available ram?

Comment: Try monitor "Res+Swap" memory, Use `top` press `f` add "USED" field then use `>` to sort by "USED" field. It could be memory leak on a tool or browser 3rd party plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently psusi was correct, and I was swapping like mad. I managed it by closing chrome tabs as soon as I noticed the symptoms and limiting the memory consumption of some programs I had running (as far as was possible).

Eventually I figured out a better solution. The real culprit was likely that my system did not have any swap partition (for some reason not automatically created during installation). Now that I've created one everything seems to be fine.